# FTP is very slow and often sent failed

Tags: php, ftp, connection

I have a bad experience of FTP, so I wonder if there is other uploading method to server side. I just want to update my server document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use system commands, and try something like scp if it's only a single file.  Of course, this assumes you have ssh available on the remote server.
(I'm also assuming this is something you're doing for configuration, not in the php application itself?)

Further to our chat, you could use the following script on your machine:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Modify hostname and filename, and confirm scp command
scp -i pem myconfig.cfg ec2-user@host:/home/ec2-user 
ssh -i pem ec2-user@host
```

And the following script in your home directory on that host:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Modify filename, and confirm which user owns the file (www-user below)
sudo cp myconfig.cfg /var/www/html
sudo chown www-user /var/www/html/myconfig.cfg
```

Comment: I do have ssh availbale on the remote server. Yeah, scp sounds resonable. I'm trying this.

Comment: If you experience timeouts and failed transfers even with scp, you can try rsync, which will allow you to resume failed transfers.  There are plenty of examples available online.

Comment: I'm learning scp now. As we know, ssh login needs a private key. When I executed command 'scp sourcefile user@remote:/destinationfolder', Command showed me 'Permission denied (publickey).lost connection'. When will Command need private key?

Comment: You'd need to set up a key pair using openssl, and configure ssh to accept this.  Here is one link (there are many others): http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/mirrors/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO-4.html . Are you doing this as part of your application, or manually from the commandline?

Comment: Commandline. I use Command on Mac.

Comment: Is the remote server setup to only allow keys, and not passwords?  Can you ssh into that server?  scp should just use whichever credentials are already in place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59041/discussion-between-anna-and-roelofs).